# Terraform - Get a value from AWS app config params and pass to resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-config, aws-app-config

How to get aws configuration parameters stored in json format on S3 in terraform scripts. I want to use those parameters in another resources.
I just want to externalise all the variable parameters in the script.

e.g: we have Data Source: aws_ssm_parameter to get AWS ssm parameters.

'''

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
}
```

'''

Similarly how can we get aws app configurations in terraform scripts.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is it exactly that you want/need? Where will those values be used? In another resource?

Comment: Yes, I want to use it in another resource.

Comment: Which resource is that? What values do you want to get from SSM?

Comment: Check I have edit my question. It can be anyresource. The parameter which are given now in config or properties file, i just want to use AWS app config instead.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need to read S3 objects' value's and use it in terraform.

Used `data` because it's external resource that we're referencing.
I would use like this:

```
data "aws_s3_object" "obj" {
  bucket = "foo"
  key    = "foo.json"
}

output "s3_json_value" {
    value = data.aws_s3_object.obj.body
}
```

To parse JSON you can use `jsondecode`

```
locals {
    a_variable = jsondecode(data.aws_s3_object.obj.body)
}

output "Username" {
    value = local.a_variable.name
}
```

Comment: using aws_s3_object directly defeats the purpose of using AWS APP Config.
I can use aws_ssm_parameter  instead to externalise the parameters that changes frequently,

Comment: Makes sense but you said `How to get aws configuration parameters stored in json format on S3 in terraform scripts.` For `I just want to externalise all the variable parameters in the script.` What do you want to use? `i just want to use AWS app config instead.` I can look at `AppConfig`